# get api worked fine but the post shows an exception while debugging in a physical device

Tags: xamarin.forms

I'm consuming some asp.net core APIs in my physical device, the get api worked fine but the post api shows an exception while debugging that tells that the url is invalid, but I tested it in swagger and it worked fine!

the exception :

> System.InvalidOperationException: An invalid request URI was provided. The request URI must either be an absolute URI or BaseAddress must be set.
> at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.PrepareRequestMessage (System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage request) [0x0008a] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/external/corefx/src/System.Net.Http/src/System/Net/Http/HttpClient.cs:678
> at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.SendAsync (System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage request, System.Net.Http.HttpCompletionOption completionOption, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x00020] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/external/corefx/src/System.Net.Http/src/System/Net/Http/HttpClient.cs:437
> at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.SendAsync (System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage request, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x00000] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/external/corefx/src/System.Net.Http/src/System/Net/Http/HttpClient.cs:418
> at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.PostAsync (System.Uri requestUri, System.Net.Http.HttpContent content, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x00013] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/external/corefx/src/System.Net.Http/src/System/Net/Http/HttpClient.cs:335
> at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.PostAsync (System.Uri requestUri, System.Net.Http.HttpContent content) [0x00000] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/external/corefx/src/System.Net.Http/src/System/Net/Http/HttpClient.cs:321
> at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.PostAsync (System.String requestUri, System.Net.Http.HttpContent content) [0x00000] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/external/corefx/src/System.Net.Http/src/System/Net/Http/HttpClient.cs:316
> at ADD.Services.ApiMachineService.AddMachine (ADD.Models.Machine machine) [0x0000f] in C:\Users\amyra\source\repos\ADD\ADD\Services\ApiMachineService.cs:22
> at ADD.ViewModels.ajoutVM.SaveMachine () [0x00072] in C:\Users\amyra\source\repos\ADD\ADD\ViewModels\ajoutVM.cs:37
> [Choreographer] Skipped 30 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.

Comment: where is the relevant code?  What URI are you passing?  The error message is very clear 'An invalid request URI was provided. The request URI must either be an absolute URI or BaseAddress must be set"

Comment: the URI is valid I tested it in postman and it worked fine

Comment: Obviously Android does not agree with you.  Android is giving you a very clear error message that what you are giving it is not acceptable.

Comment: the api is in http format, can it be the cause ?

Comment: Add the URI to question.

Comment: Also, when you receive an error message, google it. Include `android`, since running on that. See what other people did to solve it. https://www.google.com/search?q=android+An+invalid+request+URI+was+provided.+The+request+URI+must+either+be+an+absolute+URI+or+BaseAddress&rlz=1C1SQJL_enUS945US945&oq=android+An+invalid+request+URI+was+provided.+The+request+URI+must+either+be+an+absolute+URI+or+BaseAddress